# File Reading in C++ including spacebars

Tags: c++, file

I was trying to open file and read it using C++. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void open_file(string filename)
{
    string data;
    ifstream file;

    file.open(filename);
    file >> data;
    cout << data;

}

int main()
{
    open_file("file.txt");
}
```

But the output ends when character in file is space.
File:

```
This message will be printed
```

Output:

```
This
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is the standard behaviour of the extractor.

You should use `std::getline` to read a complete line. This will read until the end of a line (denoted by '\n').

So:

```
std::getline(file, data);
```

Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use **std::getline()**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void open_file(string filename)
{
    string data;
    ifstream file;

    file.open(filename);
    getline(file,data);      //This will read until the end of a line
    cout << data;

}

int main()
{
    open_file("file.txt");
}
```

Don't use **using namespace std** , refer to this for more info [Why is using namespace std bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

For more information i recommend getting used to [This site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/)